# 'StatusQuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from status.models import Status


class StatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
    model = Status
    fields = [
        'user',
        'content',
        'image'
    ]

def validate(self, data):
    content = data.get('content', None)
    if content == '':
        content = None
    image = data.get('image', None)
    if content is None and image is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Content or image is required.')
    return data
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from status.models import Status
from .serializers import StatusSerializer


class StatusListSearchAPIView(APIView):
 permission_classes = []
 authentication_classes = []

 def get(self, request):
    qs = Status.objects.all()
    serializer = StatusSerializer(qs)
    print(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


def upload_status_image(instance, filename):
    return "updates/{user}/{filename}".format(user=instance.user, filename=filename)


class StatusQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass


class StatusManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StatusQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


class Status(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_status_image, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

objects = StatusManager()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.content)[:50]

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Status post'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Status posts'
```

**error:**

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `StatusSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `StatusQuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'StatusQuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'.

Answer (score 0):

In **views.py**

Change this line :

```
 serializer = StatusSerializer(qs)
```

to this line:

```
 serializer = StatusSerializer(qs, many=True)
```